# Why do webparts have Site Collection level scope

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We can only define scope of web parts at site collection level, but I want to deploy them at web application level. Is that possible or not? And why?

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy Web Parts Farm-wide /Web application using the WebPartAdderExtension element in SharePoint 2010 , follow the below link for more information:

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Deploying-Web-Parts-Farmwide-using-the-WebPartAdderExtension-element-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: The link also holds the answer to the "why only site scope question": "Deploying Web Parts are normally done by using the Module element in the Elements manifest and using that element uploading/deploying Web Part Controls Description files (.webpart or .dwp files) into the Web Part catalog. These Element manifests for Web Parts must be scoped to the Site Collection level, since it is there where the Web Part catalog lives"